# SSL springboot Verify the connector's configuration

Tags: ssl, spring-boot

I want to use ssl in my springboot app. I use this [tutorial](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2017/01/28/ssl-configuration-on-spring-boot-application-with-self-signed-certificate/) but when I try up start my app gives me this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

And my **application.properties**

```
#ssl
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=alias
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Or do you know another way to do SSL trusted?

Answer (score 0):

Generate the key with command line running in admin mode.